# Count the number of vertices/edges existed in the graph using Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Given a list of unique keys of, let's say, 2 vertices, I could write a single Gremlin query to count the number of vertices existed in the graph. For example, vertex label 'person' has composite index on property keys 'id'. Given two ids 2 and 3, I could use this command to count how many of such persons are there:

```
g.V().or(
  has('person', 'id', 2), 
  has('person', 'id', 3)
).count()
```

This will work too, but can't be used if the unique key is on multiple property keys.

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('id', P.within(2, 3)).count()
```

**So in the case of vertices, I already had the solutions.**

Now I am having difficulty to construct a similar query to count edges, Given the list of (source, dest) such as (1, 2) and (3, 5) and edge label 'knows', I want some thing like this:

```
g.V().or(
  has('person', 'id', 1).outE('knows').where(inV().has('person', 'id', 2)), 
  has('person', 'id', 3).outE('knows').where(inV().has('person', 'id', 5))
).count()
```

I expect the above query to return 2 edges if both are found, 1 if one is found, and 0 if none is found.

However, I am getting this exception:

```
Could not find a suitable index to answer graph query and graph scans are disabled: [()]:VERTEX
```

I could not get why the above query need global graph scan. Is it a Gremlin issue, and whether it is able to fix, or to come up with a different graph traversal that returns what I want?

Thanks a lot for the support.

The Tinkerpop version I used is 3.4.6 and JanusGraph is 0.5.3.

I am asking this question since I have the data in CSV files, and the data loaded in graph and I want to write bulk queries to verify whether the two sources of data are identical. I could query each vertex or each edge individually but that is too slow.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand the question. Could you please give a more concrete example with a little sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I already deleted the post and edited the question.